# Combine publishers: notify when ANY of the publishers changes a value

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine, publisher

I'd like to trigger a "change" event on every change of either the `username` or `password` published properties and set a new `Credentials` published property derived of those two and emit an event.

What would be the simplest solution to achieve this result using SwiftUI & Combine?

Some sample code with the idea I'm trying to achieve:

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine
import Foundation

struct Credentials {
    let username: String
    let password: String

    init(username: String = "",
         password: String = "") {
        self.userName = username
        self.password = password
    }
}

final class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var username = ""
    @Published var password = ""

    @Published var credentials = Credentials()


    init() {
        [$username, $password]// ..... What to do here? 
// How to "subscribe" each of those properties to emit an event
// so that I get notified each time one of them changes

        credentials = Credentials(username: $username, password: $password)
    }
}
```

Essentially, I'm looking to something similar to this answer:
[Swift Combine: How to create a single publisher from a list of publishers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56782078/swift-combine-how-to-create-a-single-publisher-from-a-list-of-publishers)

But with the notification should be triggered each time any of the publishers produce a value, not all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `Publishers.MergeMany` as in your linked question, you want to use [`.combineLatest(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publishers/combinelatest/combinelatest(_:)) on your first publisher, like so:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import Combine
import Foundation

struct Credentials {
    let username: String
    let password: String

    init(username: String = "",
         password: String = "") {
        self.userName = username
        self.password = password
    }
}

final class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var username = ""
    @Published var password = ""

    @Published var credentials = Credentials()

    private var cancellable: Cancellable? = nil


    init() {
        cancellable = $username.combineLatest($password).sink { tuple in
            self.credentials = Credentials(username: tuple.0, password: tuple.1)
        }

        credentials = Credentials(username: username, password: password)
    }
}
```

(it's been a bit so this code may not run immediately, but hopefully you see where this is going).

Comment: What if I have 5 publishers that I want to track? 10 publishers? It's a form that I'd like to update as soon as any of the data changes. I use it to enable/disable buttons to save the data.

Comment: make a model struct(not a class) including all of those fields in your form. and add a @Published variable for that and change it whenever you want, then you can subscribe to it to get any of those changes.

Comment: @Yodagama great suggestion, that's how I ended up doing. Exactly what I was looking for, thanks!